# Configure simple firewall rules on Docker host

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a few virtual machines directly exposed on internet (i.e. the VM has a public IP address configured on its ethernet adapter) that run docker containers. I need to set up a simple firewall on those VM to allow only access on port 80 from the internet and unrestricted access from my public IP address. I noticed that Docker daemon configures some iptables chains to make its internal networking work, and when I change some rules and use iptables-save / iptables-restore, docker rules are lost and I have to restart docker service.

Is there a way to configure a few simple firewall rules on these VM without messing with Docker iptables or its configuration files? Maybe using something different from iptables? I need only to configure a couple of simple rules (as I said before, allow port 80 TCP from internet and unrestricted access from a public IP address, then block everything else)

Comment: Why not just use an existing firewall tool from your Linux distribution (e.g. firewalld, ufw, etc.)?

Comment: I am using CentOS so I could give a try to firewalld: as far as you know firewalld rules do not interfere with iptables rules?

Comment: firewalld takes over and you use it instead of iptables directly. So you can set up your desired rules in firewalld instead.